# Php and Registry Pattern

Tags: php

I'v have the folowing question. I've a Index.php which include a login.php.
In the login.php i've include a registry.php. In the login.php I add my connection object to the registry class (Registry::add($Conn)); the name of the connection class is 'conn'.

So, after the page is displayed(index.php), the user can click a button to open another page (clients\index.php). In the client\index.php i want to use the same connection. How do i do that? When i use Registry::get('conn'), i get the message that the object doesn't exist.

```
<?php
class Registry {
  /**
   * @var array The store for all of our objects
   */
  static private $_store = array();

  /**
  private static $instance = null;

  public static function getInstance() {
     if(self::$instance === null) {
        self::$instance = new Registry();
     }

     return self::$instance;
  }  

  private function __construct() {}
  private function __clone() {}
  */

  /**
   * Add an object to the registry
   * 
   * If you do not specify a name the classname is used
   *
   * @param mixed $object The object to store
   * @param string $name Name used to retrieve the object
   * @return void
   * @throws Exception
   */
  static public function add($object, $name = null)
  {

    // Use the classname if no name given, simulates singleton
    $name = (!is_null($name)) ?: get_class($object);
    $name = strtolower($name);

    if (isset(self::$_store[$name])) {
      throw new Exception("Object already exists in registry");
    }

    echo 'Connection name:' . $name;

    self::$_store[$name]= $object;
    //Undefined offset: 61
  }

  /**
   * Get an object from the registry
   *
   * @param string $name Object name, {@see self::set()}
   * @return mixed
   * @throws Exception
   */
  static public function get($name)
  {
    if (!self::contains($name)) {
      throw new Exception("Object does not exist in registry");
    }

    return self::$_store[$name];
  }

  /**
   * Check if an object is in the registry
   *
   * @param string $name Object name, {@see self::set()}
   * @return bool
   */
  static public function contains($name)
  {
    if (!isset(self::$_store[$name])) {
      return false;
    }

    return true;
  }

  /**
   * Remove an object from the registry
   *
   * @param string $name Object name, {@see self::set()}
   * @returns void
   */
  static public function remove($name)
  {
    if (self::contains($name)) {
      unset(self::$_store[$name]);
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Because in your case you need to set in Register again your connection. So, if you have one enter point for whole project(usually it is index.php file), you can call method on it to set data to register

Comment: Hi sergio thanks for your reply. Could you give me a example of your explantion. I'dont fully understand what you mean. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So, there are several methods to do it.

`First`: (not good variant because of dublicate code):

on `client/index.php` you need to set your connection again. `Registry::add($Conn)`.

`Second`: if you use some framework, you need just to add it before the script run your `client/index` controller or file(it depends what are you using).

So, the main thing if you want to get your connection object from `Registry` you need to set it per every request.

Also, for connection you can use static method, something like `app::getConnection()`, and in it you can check if connection already exist, return, if not, create a new one, without using Registry pattern.

Comment: Thanks serqio. The reason i want to use this, because i want one global connection object. Is this the right way? I'm thinking als to add a global logging class/object.

Comment: Yes, a lot of frameworks use Registry pattern insted of global variebles, but research more about this pattern. Hope, it will help.

Comment: Update the answer. check.

Comment: Hi Guys, can you give me a example of ussing app:getconnection, So that i can use one conmnection in al mine php scripts. thanks.

Comment: This is the class(for example app) in which you have static method(getConnection) to get connection object. That's all.